# PHP - fetch all then branch in PHP or query by case?

Tags: php, database

I am setting up myself a web blogging system using Codeigniter.

Now, I will need to archive all the posts and categories them into different year and topics. I guess there could be 2 different approaches that can accomplish this.
The first would be fetching all records and going through conditions to filter out each year from the posted date and the like. Then I can just pass that filtered array to the presentation for display.

An alternative would be to run multiple queries for each different needs then just fetch that query result. The downside I see from doing the latter one is ending up with too many open connections. The former one will be bad if I have huge number of records and having to fetch all.

Which way is suggested?

Comment: Running a query which selects on _both_ requirement simultaneously.

Comment: My model contains different functions that caters for corresponding actions, I guess what you are suggesting is to have different query results mixed in one function and returning this to a view?